# How to REPLACE accent characters in Opencart for SEO url

Tags: opencart, str-replace, diacritics

First of all, I am not a programmer, but I am trying to do some mods in my e-shop running on opencart so please be patient with me :) I have read tons of forums about functions and changing characters, but still couldn't find the simple answer that would help me to get it done. I am trying to make get all characters to lowercase, spaces replaced with "-" and accents replaced with similar characters.

I think this is the piece of code in Opencart I need to modify, but the question is how:

`if ($data['keyword']) { 
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($data['keyword']) . "'"); 
        }`

if I change this: 
`. $this->db->escape($data['keyword']) . "'")`

to this:
 `. $this->db->escape(strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $data['keyword']), '-')))`

it does the part of the job, but the next challenge is to get all accents replaced. I have made a function.php with this code:

```html
<?php 
 function accents($string)
  {
   //search
   $dia = array('á', 'ä', 'č', 'ď', 'é', 'ě', 'í', 'ľ', 'ĺ', 'ň', 'ó', 'ô', 'ŕ', 'ř', 'š', 'ť', 'ú', 'ů', 'ý', 'ž', 'Á', 'Ä', 'Č', 'Ď', 'É', 'Í', 'Ľ', 'Ĺ', 'Ň', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Ř', 'Š', 'Ť', 'Ú', 'Ý', 'Ž', ' ','\'','%'); 

   //replace
   $nodia = array('a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'Y', 'Z', '-','',''); 
    
   return str_replace($dia, $nodia, $string); 
  } 
?>
```

That should do the part of the trick, but I don't know how to make it work with the other part of the code.

This is the part of the product.php. The file where it needs to be aplicated..

```html
This is the part of product.php Would you please advice me what exactly and where to put?

<?php
class ModelCatalogProduct extends Model {
 public function addProduct($data) {
  $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.product.add', $data);

  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_added = NOW()");

  $product_id = $this->db->getLastId();

  if (isset($data['image'])) {
   $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = '" . $this->db->escape($data['image']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
  }

  foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
  }

  if (isset($data['product_store'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_store'] as $store_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_attribute'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_attribute'] as $product_attribute) {
    if ($product_attribute['attribute_id']) {
     foreach ($product_attribute['product_attribute_description'] as $language_id => $product_attribute_description) {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', attribute_id = '" . (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id'] . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', text = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_attribute_description['text']) . "'");
     }
    }
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_option'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_option'] as $product_option) {
    if ($product_option['type'] == 'select' || $product_option['type'] == 'radio' || $product_option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $product_option['type'] == 'image') {
     if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])) {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");

      $product_option_id = $this->db->getLastId();

      foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
       $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
      }
     }
    } else {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option['value']) . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");
    }
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_discount'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_discount'] as $product_discount) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$product_discount['customer_group_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_discount['quantity'] . "', priority = '" . (int)$product_discount['priority'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_discount['price'] . "', date_start = '" . $this->db->escape($product_discount['date_start']) . "', date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($product_discount['date_end']) . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_special'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_special'] as $product_special) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$product_special['customer_group_id'] . "', priority = '" . (int)$product_special['priority'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_special['price'] . "', date_start = '" . $this->db->escape($product_special['date_start']) . "', date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($product_special['date_end']) . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_image'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_image'] as $product_image) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($product_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$product_image['sort_order'] . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_download'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_download'] as $download_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', download_id = '" . (int)$download_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_category'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_category'] as $category_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_filter'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_filter'] as $filter_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', filter_id = '" . (int)$filter_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_related'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_related'] as $related_id) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND related_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', related_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "' AND related_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related SET product_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "', related_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_reward'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_reward'] as $customer_group_id => $product_reward) {
    if ((int)$product_reward['points'] > 0) {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', points = '" . (int)$product_reward['points'] . "'");
    }
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['product_layout'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_layout'] as $store_id => $layout_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_layout SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "', layout_id = '" . (int)$layout_id . "'");
   }
  }

  if (isset($data['keyword'])) {
   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($this->accents($data['keyword'])) . "'");
 
  }

  if (isset($data['product_recurrings'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_recurrings'] as $recurring) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_recurring` SET `product_id` = " . (int)$product_id . ", customer_group_id = " . (int)$recurring['customer_group_id'] . ", `recurring_id` = " . (int)$recurring['recurring_id']);
   }
  }

  $this->cache->delete('product');

  $this->event->trigger('post.admin.product.add', $product_id);

  return $product_id;
 }

 public function editProduct($product_id, $data) {
  $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.product.edit', $data);

  $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['image'])) {
   $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = '" . $this->db->escape($data['image']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_store'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_store'] as $store_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (!empty($data['product_attribute'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_attribute'] as $product_attribute) {
    if ($product_attribute['attribute_id']) {
     foreach ($product_attribute['product_attribute_description'] as $language_id => $product_attribute_description) {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', attribute_id = '" . (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id'] . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', text = '" .  $this->db->escape($product_attribute_description['text']) . "'");
     }
    }
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_option'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_option'] as $product_option) {
    if ($product_option['type'] == 'select' || $product_option['type'] == 'radio' || $product_option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $product_option['type'] == 'image') {
     if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])) {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");

      $product_option_id = $this->db->getLastId();

      foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
       $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['product_option_value_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
      }
     }
    } else {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option['value']) . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");
    }
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_discount'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_discount'] as $product_discount) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$product_discount['customer_group_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_discount['quantity'] . "', priority = '" . (int)$product_discount['priority'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_discount['price'] . "', date_start = '" . $this->db->escape($product_discount['date_start']) . "', date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($product_discount['date_end']) . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_special'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_special'] as $product_special) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$product_special['customer_group_id'] . "', priority = '" . (int)$product_special['priority'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_special['price'] . "', date_start = '" . $this->db->escape($product_special['date_start']) . "', date_end = '" . $this->db->escape($product_special['date_end']) . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_image'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_image'] as $product_image) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($product_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$product_image['sort_order'] . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_download'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_download'] as $download_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', download_id = '" . (int)$download_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_category'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_category'] as $category_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_filter'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_filter'] as $filter_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', filter_id = '" . (int)$filter_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE related_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_related'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_related'] as $related_id) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND related_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', related_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "' AND related_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_related SET product_id = '" . (int)$related_id . "', related_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_reward'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_reward'] as $customer_group_id => $value) {
    if ((int)$value['points'] > 0) {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', points = '" . (int)$value['points'] . "'");
    }
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_layout WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if (isset($data['product_layout'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_layout'] as $store_id => $layout_id) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_layout SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "', layout_id = '" . (int)$layout_id . "'");
   }
  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "'");

  if ($data['keyword']) {
   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($this->accents($data['keyword'])) . "'");

  }

  $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_recurring` WHERE product_id = " . (int)$product_id);

  if (isset($data['product_recurring'])) {
   foreach ($data['product_recurring'] as $product_recurring) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_recurring` SET `product_id` = " . (int)$product_id . ", customer_group_id = " . (int)$product_recurring['customer_group_id'] . ", `recurring_id` = " . (int)$product_recurring['recurring_id']);
   }
  }

  $this->cache->delete('product');

  $this->event->trigger('post.admin.product.edit', $product_id);
 }

 public function copyProduct($product_id) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

  if ($query->num_rows) {
   $data = $query->row;

   $data['sku'] = '';
   $data['upc'] = '';
   $data['viewed'] = '0';
   $data['keyword'] = '';
   $data['status'] = '0';

   $data['product_attribute'] = $this->getProductAttributes($product_id);
   $data['product_description'] = $this->getProductDescriptions($product_id);
   $data['product_discount'] = $this->getProductDiscounts($product_id);
   $data['product_filter'] = $this->getProductFilters($product_id);
   $data['product_image'] = $this->getProductImages($product_id);
   $data['product_option'] = $this->getProductOptions($product_id);
   $data['product_related'] = $this->getProductRelated($product_id);
   $data['product_reward'] = $this->getProductRewards($product_id);
   $data['product_special'] = $this->getProductSpecials($product_id);
   $data['product_category'] = $this->getProductCategories($product_id);
   $data['product_download'] = $this->getProductDownloads($product_id);
   $data['product_layout'] = $this->getProductLayouts($product_id);
   $data['product_store'] = $this->getProductStores($product_id);
   $data['product_recurrings'] = $this->getRecurrings($product_id);

   $this->addProduct($data);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the insert query happens in the model you can call it by adding the function as a class method somewhere in the model file **product.php**:

```
public function accents($string) {
    //search
    $dia = array('á', 'ä', 'č', 'ď', 'é', 'ě', 'í', 'ľ', 'ĺ', 'ň', 'ó', 'ô', 'ŕ', 'ř', 'š', 'ť', 'ú', 'ů', 'ý', 'ž', 'Á', 'Ä', 'Č', 'Ď', 'É', 'Í', 'Ľ', 'Ĺ', 'Ň', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Ř', 'Š', 'Ť', 'Ú', 'Ý', 'Ž', ' ','\'','%'); 

    //replace
    $nodia = array('a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'I', 'L', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'Y', 'Z', '-','',''); 

    return str_replace($dia, $nodia, $string); 
}
```

And then call it in the insert like this:

```
$this->db->escape($this->accents($data['keyword']))
```

Of course if you want to apply that `preg_replace()` as well this can get messy and you might want to think about formatting it before the insert in steps for clarity.  You could add a block like this and then just leave the query alone - which I might add has the added benefit of not breaking extensions and vQmods which might depend on the default code syntax:

```
$data['keyword'] = $this->accents($data['keyword'];
$data['keyword'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $data['keyword']);
$data['keyword'] = trim($data['keyword'], '-');
$data['keyword'] = strtolower($data['keyword']);
```

You could also try just converting to ascii with `iconv()` like this:

```
$this->db->escape(iconv("UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$data['keyword']))
```

I've used the above function for some webservices calls that require ascii and it works for me.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks a lot for your answer. I tried the option with iconv first, but it  replaced accents with "?" Now I am trying to use accents function but I am doing something wrong. I am getting  Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelCatalogProduct::accents() in /home/public_html/web/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 270. I am not sure how to add the function as a class method somewhere in that model file product.php

Comment: I've demonstrated that in the first block.  Just add it at the end before the class is closed.  If you are unsure take a close look at all the other methods and the way they appear.  You just need to add it the same way as all the other methods - much like a regular function but just make sure it's inside the class `{` braces `}`